# Store array in MySQL using PHP one by one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ii have stored an array list using

```
<?php
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
include("mydb.php");
$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($array));
mysql_query("insert into tsest (array) values('$array_string')",$con) or die("not updated");
?>
```

now i want to update that field with a new array but don't delete previeus one i used

```
   <?php
$array = array("aaa");
include("mydb.php");
$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($array));

$sql= 'select * from tsest where uname = "manoj" ';    
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
$value=$row['array'];
mysql_query('UPDATE tsest SET array="'.$array_string.'"'.$value.' where uname="manoj"',$con) or die("hello");

?>
```

but it didn't work

Comment: "*but it didn't work*" is not a valid MySQL error message (and although I don't know PHP, I'm pretty sure it isn't a valid PHP error message either)

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? It didn't do anything? It updated everything? The wrong fields? The right fields with the wrong data?

Comment: if the value is null in that field then it updates but if array is stored previously then it didn't update and the die statement executes

Comment: You should first get existing serialized array from the db (`SELECT`), unserialize it, update in PHP, serialize again and put back to MySQL (`UPDATE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have serialized your array before you store it, but you need to unserialize before you can add to it.

```
$value=unserialize($row['array']);
```

You also need to merge the arrays, doing a $array_string.'"'.$value will not work.

Try this:

```
$newArray = mysql_escape_string(serialize(array_merge($value, $array_string)));
mysql_query('UPDATE tsest SET array="'.$newArray.' where uname="manoj"',$con) or die("hello");
```

Comment: He is serializing his array before storing it.  I don't agree with the way he's doing it, but it solves the issue he is experiencing.

Comment: Ah, the serialize wasn't there when I posted the comment. =)

Comment: Ah, sorry, yeah.  Saved my edit just as you commented I think :P

Answer (score 0):

When you save the array like this

```
mysql_query("insert into tsest (array) values('$array_string')",$con) or die("not updated");
```

Then you are not saving a username along with this data. However when you are trying to fetch it you are using a username

```
$sql= 'select * from tsest where uname = "manoj" ';
```

Same for update. Hence the update doesn't work because your array was not saved for a username `manoj`

So Therefore when you save the array you have to also save the username in your table

Answer (score 0):

there is some error with your update sql
and serialized value can not be simply joined to produce a new array
try code below

```
   <?php

   $array = array("aaa"); include("mydb.php"); $sql= 'select * from
   tsest where uname = "manoj" ';

------------------------------------------------------------------------

   $result = mysql_query($sql,$con); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
   $value=$row['array']; $new_array = array_merge($array,
   unserialize($value)); array_string =
   mysql_escape_string(serialize($new_array)); mysql_query('UPDATE tsest
   SET array="'.$array_string.'"'.' where uname="manoj"',$con) or
   die("hello");

?>
```